# How to do classic ASP debugging without Visual Studio (or any other 3rd party tools)?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, iis-6

I am supporting an application written in classic ASP with IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003. I have NO priviledges to add or configure any of the software on this purely development use server, so I cannot install any 3rd party tools. I have requested and requested Visual Studio, but the system admin is old school and says we don't need that for classic ASP development. So... we're stuck with Notepad and IE 7.

The sys admin says that both client-side and server-side debugging is turned on in IIS and that IIS was restarted after the change. However, I can't get any response from the script debugger when I insert a stop statement or a 1/0 expression. (I do get appropriate error messages on the page - just no debugger.)

I have both checkboxes cleared in Internet Options/Advanced so IE and Other debugging will be allowed.

What else do I need? What am I missing? Maybe the script debugger isn't installed? How can I tell?

Comment: I have only had this working on a system where the debugger (VS or MS script debugger) is on the webserver itself. I'm not actually sure if you can debug on a remote server at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to modify the script to output your own debug information to the browser.

You can't STOP server-side code using this technique, but you can spit out the value of any data to variables you think are relevant to solving the problem. If you're worried about users seeing the debug code you can wrap the output in HTML comments `<!-- ... -->` and view the page srouce.

Comment: This is a development-only server, so I'm not worried about users seeing the code. I'm using response.write to output values, but it's painful. They've got includes all over the place, variables being built across multiple pages, function calls to other pages - can you say 'spaghetti'?

Comment: I just went ahead and selected your answer. In all my research, I've found that using Response.Write statements sprinkled through the code is really the only way to debug this thing.